# Code works properly but shows data for all users

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, joomla-3.6, php7

I am using the latest RS Form Pro with Joomla 3.9, Platform 13.1.0.

My code is working properly (thank you guys!) But the data should be limited to each user. The user ID is is not in the table specified in the code so I assume that's why you get to see everyone's commissions instead of just yours. The table with the user info is jos_users. When you enable an RSform module you specify "login" as to show only the users submissions. Does that matter? How can I adjust this? Many thanks!

Here is the code:

```
$months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
$monthlySums = array_fill_keys($months, 0);

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select("FieldName, SUM(FieldValue) AS Sum")
    ->from("#__rsform_submission_values")
    ->where([
        "FormId = 46", 
        "FieldName IN (" . implode(',', $db->q($months)) . ")"
    ])
    ->group("FieldName");

//JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($query->dump(), 'info');  // never show dump() to public

try {
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $objects = $db->loadObjectList();
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        $monthlySums[$object->FieldName] += $object->Sum;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');  // never show getMessage() to public
}

foreach ($monthlySums as $month => $sum) {
    echo "<div>{$month}: {$sum}</div>";
}

SQL Query:
```

Comment: We will need to better understand how you are relating/storing the user_id in your database.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The user id is assigned to each Joomla user when they register on the site. So when I publish a form, RSForm assigns the the Joomla user (user id) to the submission. The user id's are stored in another table called "jos_users." The script adds up all the commissions for all users. The form itself has no fields and displays information gathered from another form, "Form 46" so it's bypassing the logged in user I guess... I'm not sure how to proceed. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I am away on holidays, so I cannot access my project with RSForm data in it.  With all due respect, it looks like you have simply dumped my last answer and added a new requirement.  We want you to go on the development journey before posting a new question.  Please research how to retrieve the current user's id, investigate how the user_id relates to the rsforms data in the database, and research how to join tables and relate data using a "pivot" (here's a hint: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23860/12352). We want to help, but we want to see your effort first.

Comment: I would like you to read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333953/2943403  Without seeing the specifics, I have a blind guess that looks like this: https://3v4l.org/OHRfV  However this is not tested and I am not confident about the result.  If you can offer some sample data or feedback from my suggestion, I may be able to post an answer.

Comment: I will read it! Because the user id is not in the same table I created a new field in my form to capture the user id and enter it in the table. It is called "Member".  It worked. Now I have the user ID in the same table. I have been trying to figure out how to query it from Phpmy admin but because I am not the logged in user it doesnt make sense to me. That's how I got stuck.

Comment: It is inadvisable to store the userid in the `#__rsform_submission_values` table.  This will lead to unnecessary database bloat and less efficient queries.  If it not too late for you to adjust your thinking, please consider removing the `Member` field from your form and let RSForms store it properly in the `#__rsform_submissions` table where there is already a dedicated column for the value.  I will need to see exported (easily done via phpMyAdmin Export as text) data to fully understand your scenario.

Comment: Will do! I think I've had enough for today lol Stay tuned!

Comment: I want to help you toward a resoltion, but we need more concrete details to progress.  Please adjust your form so that the user id is only stored in the `#__rsform_submissions` table, then show us some sample data from `#__rsform_submissions` and `#__rsform_submission_values` so that an accurate query can be suggested.

Comment: Please don't abandon this page.  How can I assist you?

Comment: I have a tendency to be very generous regarding mysql questions.  Here is a recent one: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/28014/12352  I am very confident that I can help you to interrogate your rsform data, but I will need a db-fiddle.com demo link from you so that I can test my advice.